Crear multiples Topic con Apache Kafka
Estoy empezando en el mundo de streaming de data con Apache Kafka. En este proceso de aprendizaje estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto de practica de ingesta de datos con la utilizando la API de Coincap (https://docs.coincap.io/#89deffa0-ab03-4e0a-8d92-637a857d2c91)
Estoy utilizando la librería de Confluent Kafka, la cual quiero que por un conjunto de criptomoneda generar un topic con 3 particiones cada una. Mi principal problema es que no logro enviar los mensajes que genera la API de Coincap a cada topic, es decir la información de Bitcoin al topic Bitcoin, la información de Ethereum al topic de Ethereum y así sucesivamente.
Tengo 3 archivos: producer_api.py, pipeline_data.py y main.py
Código producer_api.py
from confluent_kafka import Producer
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic
import json

# Obtener las variables necesarias desde el config.json:

#with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
    #config = json.load(config_file)

#topic_name = {config.get('topic_name')}

servers = "localhost:9092"
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': servers,
        'partitioner': 'consistent_random'}


producer = Producer(conf)

# Definiendo funciones de Kafka

def configure_create_topics(topics:list, servers:str=servers) -> None:
    '''Configura y crea los topics necesarios para el cluster kafka.'''

    a = AdminClient(conf)

    # Estableciendo la configuración de los topics
    topics = [NewTopic(topic, num_partitions=3) 
              for topic in topics]

    # Llamar create_topics para crear topics de manera asíncrona, un diccionario
    # de <topic,future> es devuelto.
    fs = a.create_topics(topics, request_timeout=15.0)

    # Esperar a que finalice la operación.
    # Todos los futuros terminaran en el mismo tiempo.
    
    for topic, f in fs.items():
        try:
            f.result()  # The result itself is None
            print(f"Topic {topic} creado")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"No se pudo crear el topic {topic}: {e}")

def send_message(message, name_topic:str, id:str) -> None:    
    '''Comienza a enviar mensajes y crea una clave de mensaje para cada mensaje.
    Cada clave se crea tomando las dos primeras letras del topic en mayúscula y
    la identificación de la crypto'''
   
    try:
        #producer.send(topic, value=message.encode('utf-8'))
        #producer.produce(topic = name_topic, value=json.dumps(val), key=f"{name_topic[:3]}{id}".encode('utf-8'))
        producer.produce(topic = name_topic, value=message.encode('utf-8'), key=f"{name_topic[:3]}{id}".encode('utf-8'))
        producer.flush()
        print(f"Produced: {message} to Kafka topic: {name_topic}")
    except Exception as error:
        print(f"Error: {error}")

El otro archivo pipeline_data.py
import time
import requests
import datetime
from producer_api import send_message
import threading
import datetime


tags = ["Bitcoin","Ethereum","Ripple","Litecoin","Cardano","Dash","Monero"]
cryptos = ["bitcoin","ethereum","ripple","litecoin","cardano","dash","monero"]
url_api = "https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets"

def producer_thread():

    while True:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url_api)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                data = response.json()

                #Verificar la estructura de la respuesta
                if 'data' in data and isinstance(data['data'], list):
                    # Crear una lista de diccionarios con la información
                    rows = [{'datetime': str(datetime.datetime.now()), 'name': crypto['name'], 'symbol': crypto['symbol'], 'price' : crypto['priceUsd']} for crypto in data['data'] if crypto['id'] in cryptos]
                    
                    #Enviar los datos a Kafka
                    for row in rows:      #accedemos a cada elemento de la lista (en este caso cada elemento es un dictionario)
                        for k,v in row.items(): #acedemos a cada llave(k), valor(v) de cada diccionario 
                            if v['name'] == 'bitcoin':
                                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                                name = row['name']
                                symbol = row['symbol']
                                price = row['price']
                                # Produce data to Kafka topic
                                message = f"{current_datetime}, {name}, {symbol}, {price}"
                                send_message(message, name_topic= "Bitcoin", id=symbol)
                            
                            if v['name'] == 'ethereum':
                                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                                name = row['name']
                                symbol = row['symbol']
                                price = row['price']
                                # Produce data to Kafka topic
                                message = f"{current_datetime}, {name}, {symbol}, {price}"
                                send_message(message, name_topic= "Ethereum", id=symbol)

                            if v['name'] == 'ripple':
                                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                                name = row['name']
                                symbol = row['symbol']
                                price = row['price']
                                # Produce data to Kafka topic
                                message = f"{current_datetime}, {name}, {symbol}, {price}"
                                send_message(message, name_topic= "Ripple", id=symbol)

                            if v['name'] == 'litecoin':
                                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                                name = row['name']
                                symbol = row['symbol']
                                price = row['price']
                                # Produce data to Kafka topic
                                message = f"{current_datetime}, {name}, {symbol}, {price}"
                                send_message(message, name_topic= "Litecoin", id=symbol)

                            if v['name'] == 'cardano':
                                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                                name = row['name']
                                symbol = row['symbol']
                                price = row['price']
                                # Produce data to Kafka topic
                                message = f"{current_datetime}, {name}, {symbol}, {price}"
                                send_message(message, name_topic= "Cardano", id=symbol)

                            if v['name'] == 'dash':
                                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                                name = row['name']
                                symbol = row['symbol']
                                price = row['price']
                                # Produce data to Kafka topic
                                message = f"{current_datetime}, {name}, {symbol}, {price}"
                                send_message(message, name_topic= "Dash", id=symbol)

                            if v['name'] == 'monero':
                                current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
                                name = row['name']
                                symbol = row['symbol']
                                price = row['price']
                                # Produce data to Kafka topic
                                message = f"{current_datetime}, {name}, {symbol}, {price}"
                                send_message(message, name_topic= "Monero", id=symbol)

                            else:
                                print("No existe el nombre de la criptomoneda.")

                                                                   
                else:
                    print("La estructura de la respuesta no es la esperada.")
  
            else:
                print(f"Error al realizar la solicitud a la API. Código de estado: {response.status_code}")
        
            time.sleep(30)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error en producer_thread: {str(e)}")


# Crear hilos separados para el producer y el consumer
producer_thread = threading.Thread(target=producer_thread)

# Comenzar los hilos
producer_thread.start()

# Esperar por los hilos hasta finalizar (lo que nunca sucederá en este caso ya que se ejecutan infinitamente)
producer_thread.join()

codigo main.py
from pipeline_data1 import producer_thread
from producer_api1 import configure_create_topics
import json

with open('config.json', 'r') as config_file:
    config = json.load(config_file)

#topic_name = {config.get('topic_name')}
#cryptos = {config.get('cryptos')}
#url_api = {config.get('api_url')}
tags = {config.get('tags')}

#servers = "localhost:9092"
#conf = {'bootstrap.servers': servers,
        #'partitioner': 'consistent_random'}

def main():

    # Estableciendo topics
    configure_create_topics(topics=tags)
    
    # Producir mensajes de la API
    producer_thread()
    
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

A pesar de lo anterior no logro conectar con los Topics porque me dice que no se encuentra el Topic, ¿Alguna Sugerencia?
